# Android Market Statistics API?

Tags: android, web-services, statistics, google-play

Is there an API or webservice we could use to get statistics about an app in the Android Market?
Like AndroidZoom.com and AndroLib.com. Both sites have a lot of info about apps.
Where did the data come from?
Thanks for replying.

Regards, Rick

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with this open-source API for the Android Market:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/